# Toggle Text with Jquery with Text Displays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I am using Jquery to toggle the display on certain P tags. When the "More" is clicked all of the text is displayed. I want the click listener to say "Less" when the content has been displayed. At this point it says "More" all the time. I need to change the "More" to "Less" on toggle. I have been able to achieve this by removing the classes that allow the text to be shown and hidden, this defeats the purpose because it's that very functionality that I care about.

Working Text Display:

http://jsfiddle.net/5UgfH/

Working More/Less Toggle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LKJ5N/

```
<p> Please Help </p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just comment out the `h3` hiding logic (from your first fiddle):

```
 //$("#moretext").click(function () {
 //    $('h3', this).toggle();
 //});
```

Check if this works: http://jsfiddle.net/5UgfH/1/

Comment: That Worked! Thanks So Much. I thought that code was necessary. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin, it should do the trick. [jQuery expander](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/)

Comment: I am so close. I kinda just want to get the code I currently have to work.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really have to use two elements for that, just swap the text.
You'd do that like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".showhidetext").hide();
    var more = $('<h3 />', {id   :'more', 
                            text :'MORE',
                            on   : {
                                    click: function() {
                                      $(".showhidetext").toggle();
                                      $(this).text(function(_,txt) {
                                          return txt == 'MORE'?'LESS':'MORE';
                                      })
                                    }
                                }
                            }
               );
    $('#moretext').append(more);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5UgfH/4/)

**Note that ID's are unique**, and you can only have the same ID once in the document, so change `#showhidetext` to a class instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#showhidetext").toggle()
    var more_texts = ['MORE','LESS'];
    var text_flag = 0;
         $("#moretext").click(function(){
             $('#showhidetext').toggle();
             $(this).text(more_texts[++text_flag%2]);
         });
});
```

This way you won't need to hide/show the text that triggers the text `.toggle()`, just style `#showhidetext` as you need

[**<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/5UgfH/)